# Spinner not working in android,

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have made a simple demo for spinners in android,In that 2 activities are there in first activity a simple spinner and in second a textView.So when any item fromthe spinner is selected it will be displayed on the second Activity,i have tried the following code but its not working:

**Activity1.java**

```
package com.example.sppiner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String[] s={"ahmedabad","baroda","chitor","daman","england","france","georgia"};

        sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,s));
        sp.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String n = (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
            Bundle b =new Bundle();
            i.putExtra("nat", n);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**act2.java**

```
  package com.example.sppiner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Act2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_act2);
        TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent i =getIntent();
        String nat = b.getString("nat");
        tv.setText(nat);




    }



}
```

Please help me...thanks in advance

Comment: i ahve removed it...still not solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Ist activity, do this:

```
sp.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String n = (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
            i.putExtra("nat", n);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

And, in your 2nd activity, do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act2);
    TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    String nat = getIntent().getStringExtra("nat");
    tv.setText(nat);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use `setOnItemSelectedListener` for `spinner`

```
cat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
String n = (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
Bundle b =new Bundle();
i.putExtra("nat", n);
startActivity(i);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
});
```

and in second activity

```
String city =b.getString("nat");
```

use this line instead of

```
String city =b.getString("city");
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this.

you need to get the value by given `key` in previous `activity`. i.e `nat`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Intent i =getIntent();
            Bundle b =i.getExtras();
            String city =b.getStringExtras("nat");
            tv.setText(city);
        }
```

Comment: and also change this line                                          Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class); into          Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);

Comment: I have edited my code ..still having problem..please recheck it..dear

Comment: @vinoth No vinoth. It is `Act2.class` only. see his class name and file name.

Comment: @Gunaseelan no guna he has just edited his code previously it was like that.

Comment: @Vinoth Okay vinoth fine. I saw it now only.